# Submitting data with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm learning AJAX and jQuery and I'm trying to put together a simple test script that will take 2 `input` fields and insert the data to my database. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, but the code below won't insert the data. can anyone spot my problem?

I'm not getting any errors and I don't see anything weird in the console.

HTML

```
<input id="name" type="text"/>
<input id="LastName" type="text"/>
<button id="testButton">Button</button>
<div id="callback"></div>
```

JS

```
$('#testButton').click(function () {
    var firstName = $("#name").val();
    var lastName = $("#LastName").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "insert.php",
      data: { name: firstName, LastName: lastName }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
});
```

PHP

```
    //Adding to the local database
    $name = array($_POST['name'], $_POST['LastName']);

    $qry = $dbh->prepare(
        'INSERT INTO info (FirstName, LastName) VALUES (?,?)');

    if ($qry->execute($name)) {
        echo "Success";
    }
```

Comment: Are you connecting? or any errors?

Comment: Yes, the connection is in the PHP file, I just didn't include it here

Comment: Html and Js seem fine. Does the query execute in a non-AJAX PHP file?

Comment: You might be missing  setParameters on the query

Comment: @Cranio - Yes, I just realized I forgot the `name` attribute on the text fields. After changing that and submitting via a `form` it worked. However, the AJAX still isn't working

Comment: try this :  data: { name: "ABC", LastName: "DEF" }

Comment: Try using your browser's developer tools to watch what's happening with the AJAX POST. Are the correct values in the request body? In this context you could also try having your PHP print the values it's getting (to see them in your developer tools).

Comment: All of your code is fine. You must not be including a file properly

Comment: what jquery version are you using ?

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I'll take a look on monday when I get back to work. I don't have the full code with me at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS code is working just fine but with jsfiddle echo service.

```
$('#testButton').click(function () {
    var firstName = $("#name").val();
    var lastName = $("#LastName").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/echo/html/",
      data: { name: firstName, LastName: lastName }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
});​
```

here is the link : http://jsfiddle.net/TPu8X/
another version : http://jsfiddle.net/TPu8X/1/

Your code will only work with  `jquery 1.5.2` or later (May be you are using an older version)

It seems you are not having your `insert.php` at correct path.So try placing php at correct path.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, Sorry for the delay. Thanks for setting up the jsfiddle. I checked my code again, and if I change `$('testButton')` to `$('html')` I can get the script to execute. So, that tells me there is something wrong with the `$('testButton')` selector, however, I can't find anything wrong. Any idea?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of jquery using `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Paul . Try this : $('#testButton').live('click',function(){    ..... Here is a demo. [http://jsfiddle.net/TPu8X/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/TPu8X/4/)

Comment: Cancel that, it worked :) (Typo on my part) So, what's the difference between the original code and `.live`? THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentionned, inputs need a "name" attribute. So HTML is ok now.

If your PHP is working correctly, then you should take a look at your JS.

I think this code is not executed. http://api.jquery.com/ready/ Try to encapsulate your JS code within this code :

```
$(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

You can also use the "Network" and "Console" tabs of Google Chrome's inspector for a better understanding of what's going on with your ajax request.

"Network" will show you HTTP requests and their responses (if any).
Also try to insert some

```
console.log('message')
```

in your JS and take a look at the console for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `success` function in the ajax call.

```
$('#testButton').click(function () {
    var firstName = $("#name").val();
    var lastName = $("#LastName").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "insert.php",
      data: { name: firstName, LastName: lastName }
      success: function(data) {
        alert("sucess" + data);
      }
    });
});
```

Also, the button might still be performing the submission after you click it if it's inside a `form` element, add "return false" at the end of the function it triggers to avoid this.

Comment: The jqXHR.success() callback will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8 ,so you better use new callback jqXHR.done().